# Is there a way to Backup/Stop and Restore/Start a GKE Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE Cluster runs on minimum 3 VM nodes and there is no way to Stop/Suspend the cluster like VMs to avoid burning money when you are not using it. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Scale down to 0 worker nodes.

Comment: 3 nodes is not the hard minimum, just the recommended min. you can reduce if needed.

Comment: Even after scaling your GKE cluster to 0 nodes, you still can be charged for some GKE related services, like Stackdriver monitoring. You can lower stand-by costs by disabling it, but it would be impossible to debug cluster issues with disabled Stackdriver. If it's not super complex cluster configuration, with many operators and CRDs, think about creating GKE cluster on demand and deleting it when you don't need it any more. It takes more time to create GKE cluster, that to scale up node pool, but it could be more convenient for some use cases.

Comment: Starting from June 6 2020, GKE management fee will cost you $0.10 per cluster per hour (around $73.00 per month), irrespective of cluster size and topology. One zonal cluster per billing account is still free.
 https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/fdgblk/google_gke_to_introduce_management_fees_by_june/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by user @Hitobat:

> 3 nodes is not the hard minimum, just the recommended min. you can reduce if needed.

You can create your cluster with only 1 node.

**If you try to create cluster with only a default node-pool with less than 3 nodes you will get below warning message:**

- > Clusters smaller than 3 nodes may experience **downtime during upgrades**

---

There are several ways to reduce costs associated with running a `GKE` cluster:

### Scale down to 0 worker nodes

As pointed by user: @Amit Kumar Gupta:

> Scale down to 0 worker nodes

Please take in mind that if you scale your `default-pool` to 0 you will need to manually increase it's size when additional resources are required. You can manage the amount of nodes in the cluster by invoking below `gcloud` command:

`$ gcloud container clusters resize CLUSTER_NAME --node-pool NODE_POOL_NAME --num-nodes NUMBER_OF_NODES --zone ZONE`

### Enable auto scaling for your cluster

You can enable auto scaling for your cluster to reduce and increase amount of nodes in node pools automatically based on the cluster resources usage. There is an official documentation about it: [Cloud.google.com: Kuberentes Engine: Cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler)

Take in mind that you can manually scale your cluster to 0 nodes even if auto scaling enabled but **auto scaler will not scale up from 0 nodes.**

### Preemptible VM's

You have an option to run preemptible VM's with your `GKE` cluster. You can find more information about it here: [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Preemptible VM's](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms)

---

Please take a look on additional links:

- [Medium.com: Google Cloud: Scale your Kubernetes cluster to almost zero with gke autoscaler](https://medium.com/google-cloud/scale-your-kubernetes-cluster-to-almost-zero-with-gke-autoscaler-9c78051cbf40)
- [Medium.com: Google Cloud: Cutting costs on Kubernetes cluster gke concepts](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cutting-costs-on-kubernetes-cluster-gke-concepts-applied-cc340eba0bec)
- [Cloud.google.com: Blog: Cutting costs with Google Kubernetes Engine using the cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/cutting-costs-with-google-kubernetes-engine-using-the-cluster-autoscaler-and-preemptible-vms)
- [Cloud.google.com: Kuberentes Engine: Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing)